# Geometric interpretation of Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: covariance-matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, geometry, cholesky-decomposition

I understand that a square matrix, say $A$, can be thought of as a linear transformation within the same space. I could be as simple as basis change or some other transformation.

In this way of interpretation, how to understand/make sense of Cholesky Decomposition (both classical version and LDL* Decomposition)? From an answer in quora I gather it is related to inner-product but didn't understand that too well.

I know this question can be posted on Mathematics but given the heavy use of linear algebra in Multivariate statistics, I though I might get a good answer here.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruhat_decomposition.

Comment: @whuber tried reading about this. Seems too generic so maybe Cholesky is a form of this in linear algebra but it didn't really help. Thanks anyway for the reference.

Comment: The Bruhat decomposition provides a deep "geometric interpretation," as you requested.  Rather than "generic" it is an insightful *generalization.*

Comment: I actually did mean generalization by generic. Anyway, I am still looking for a rather focussed interpretation of Cholesky Decomposition.

Comment: The symmetric positive-definite matrix encodes an inner product on some lattice in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ . You can change the basis of this lattice using Gram–Schmidt process